# How to extract a repeated nested field from json string and join with existing repeated nested field in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with one nested repeated field called `article_id` and a string field  that contains a json string.

Here is the schema of my table:

[image]

Here is an example row of the table:

```
[
  {
"article_id": "2732930586",
"author_names": [
  {
    "AuN": "h kanahashi",
    "AuId": "2591665239",
    "AfN": null,
    "AfId": null,
    "S": "1"
  },
  {
    "AuN": "t mukai",
    "AuId": "2607493793",
    "AfN": null,
    "AfId": null,
    "S": "2"
  },
  {
    "AuN": "y yamada",
    "AuId": "2606624579",
    "AfN": null,
    "AfId": null,
    "S": "3"
  },
  {
    "AuN": "k shimojima",
    "AuId": "2606600298",
    "AfN": null,
    "AfId": null,
    "S": "4"
  },
  {
    "AuN": "m mabuchi",
    "AuId": "2606138976",
    "AfN": null,
    "AfId": null,
    "S": "5"
  },
  {
    "AuN": "t aizawa",
    "AuId": "2723380540",
    "AfN": null,
    "AfId": null,
    "S": "6"
  },
  {
    "AuN": "k higashi",
    "AuId": "2725066679",
    "AfN": null,
    "AfId": null,
    "S": "7"
  }
],
"extra_informations": "{
\"DN\": \"Experimental study for improvement of crashworthiness in AZ91 magnesium foam controlling its microstructure.\",
\"S\":[{\"Ty\":1,\"U\":\"https://shibaura.pure.elsevier.com/en/publications/experimental-study-for-improvement-of-crashworthiness-in-az91-mag\"}],
 \"VFN\":\"Materials Science and Engineering\",
 \"FP\":283,
 \"LP\":287,
 \"RP\":[{\"Id\":2024275625,\"CoC\":5},{\"Id\":2035451257,\"CoC\":5},     {\"Id\":2141952446,\"CoC\":5},{\"Id\":2126566553,\"CoC\":6},  {\"Id\":2089573897,\"CoC\":5},{\"Id\":2069241702,\"CoC\":7},  {\"Id\":2000323790,\"CoC\":6},{\"Id\":1988924750,\"CoC\":16}],
\"ANF\":[
{\"FN\":\"H.\",\"LN\":\"Kanahashi\",\"S\":1},
{\"FN\":\"T.\",\"LN\":\"Mukai\",\"S\":2},    
{\"FN\":\"Y.\",\"LN\":\"Yamada\",\"S\":3},    
{\"FN\":\"K.\",\"LN\":\"Shimojima\",\"S\":4},    
{\"FN\":\"M.\",\"LN\":\"Mabuchi\",\"S\":5},    
{\"FN\":\"T.\",\"LN\":\"Aizawa\",\"S\":6},    
{\"FN\":\"K.\",\"LN\":\"Higashi\",\"S\":7}
],
\"BV\":\"Materials Science and Engineering\",\"BT\":\"a\"}"
  }
]
```

In the `extra_information.ANF` I have an nested array that contains some more author name information.

The nested repeated `author_name` field has a sub-field `author_name.S` which can be mapped into `extra_informations.ANF.S` for a join. Using this mapping I am trying to achieve the following table:

```
| article_id | author_names.AuN | S | extra_information.ANF.FN | extra_information.ANF.LN|
| 2732930586 |  h kanahashi     | 1 | H.                       | Kanahashi               | 
| 2732930586 |  t mukai         | 2 | T.                       | Mukai                   | 
| 2732930586 |  y yamada        | 3 | Y.                       | Yamada.                 |
| 2732930586 |  k shimojima     | 4 | K.                       | Shimojima               |
| 2732930586 |  m mabuchi       | 5 | M.                       | Mabuchi                 |
| 2732930586 |  t aizawa        | 6 | T.                       | Aizawa                  |
| 2732930586 |  k higashi       | 7 | K.                       | Higashi                 |
```

The primary problem I faced is that when I convert a json_string using `JSON_EXTRACT(extra_information,"$.ANF")`, it does not give me an array, instead it gives me the string format of the nested repeated array, which I could not convert into an array.

Is it possible to produce such table using standards-sql in bigquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Option 1

This is based on REGEXP_REPLACE function and few more functions (REPLACE, SPLIT, etc.) to manipulate with result. Note - we need extra manipulation because wildcards and filters are not supported in JsonPath expressions in BigQuery?

```sql
#standard SQL
SELECT 
  article_id, author.AuN, author.S, 
  REPLACE(SPLIT(extra, '","')[OFFSET(0)], '"FN":"', '') FirstName,
  REPLACE(SPLIT(extra, '","')[OFFSET(1)], 'LN":"', '') LastName
FROM `table` , UNNEST(author_names) author
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(extra_informations, '$.ANF'), r'\[{|}\]', ''), '},{')) extra
ON author.S = CAST(REPLACE(SPLIT(extra, '","')[OFFSET(2)], 'S":', '') AS INT64)
```

> Option 2

To overcome BigQuery "limitation" for JsonPath, you can use [custom function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) as the example below shows:
Note : it uses jsonpath-0.8.0.js that can be downloaded from https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsonpath/downloads and assumed to be uploaded to Google Cloud Storage - gs://your_bucket/jsonpath-0.8.0.js

```sql
#standard SQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json STRING, json_path STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
    try { var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
        return jsonPath(parsed, json_path);
    } catch (e) { return null }
"""
OPTIONS (
    library="gs://your_bucket/jsonpath-0.8.0.js"
);
SELECT 
  article_id, author.AuN, author.S,
  CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(extra_informations, CONCAT('$.ANF[?(@.S==', CAST(author.S AS STRING), ')].FN')) FirstName,
  CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(extra_informations, CONCAT('$.ANF[?(@.S==', CAST(author.S AS STRING), ')].LN')) LastName
FROM `table`, UNNEST(author_names) author
```

As you can see  - now you can do all magic in one simple JsonPath

Comment: Both of the solution worked for me but I particularly liked the flexibility of json path. Thank you!